# Fixing Codeigniter Active Record update query

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a class for handling model in Codeigniter app

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    const DB_TABLE = 'abstract';
    const DB_TABLE_PK = 'abstract';

    private function update() {
        $this->db->update($this::DB_TABLE, $this, $this::DB_TABLE_PK);
    }
    public function save() {
        if (isset($this->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK})) {
            $this->update();
        }
        else {
            $this->insert();
        }}
```

And this is a model extended from above class:

```
class Projects extends MY_Model {

    const DB_TABLE = 'projects';
    const DB_TABLE_PK = 'project_id';


    public $project_id;
    public $project_name;
    public $project_investment;
    public $project_employment;
    public $project_province;
    public $project_city;
    public $project_address;
    public $project_estimate;
    public $project_duration;
    public $project_construction;
}
```

According to Codeigniter User Guide, i think there is a problem in 3rd parameter of Update query (It just  send DB_TABLE_PK name ,in this case 'project_id' ) but since i'm new to OOP , don't know how to fix it .

Codeigniter User Guide :

```
$this->db->update('mytable', $data, "id = 4");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it :

```
private function update() {
    $value=$this::DB_TABLE_PK;
    $this->db->update($this::DB_TABLE, $this, $this::DB_TABLE_PK.' = '.$this->$value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[guide clrearly says](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

```
$data_array = array();
$where_array = array();
$this->db->update('table_name', $where_array, $data_array());
```

so example

```
$data_array = array('name' => 'Alpha', 'gender' => 'male'); // change column name to "Alpha", and gender column to 'male'
$where_array = array('id' => '4', 'allowed' => '1'); // update row with $data_array where id = 4 and allowed = 1
$this->db->update('person', $where_array, $data_array());
```

I strongly recommend you to use profiler `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` put this anywhere in controller and under your page there will be "profiler" is shows post/get data queries, sessions and all usefull information while developing.

Comment: And my problem is how to write this id value (4) in OOP method ?

Comment: you have to use `array()` structure, or as you wrote `$this->db->update('mytable', $data, "id = 4");`. At this point I think I do not understand your question completely.

Answer (score 0):

The function above doe not seem to have the complete WHERE statement for the update()

```
$this->db->update($this::DB_TABLE, $this, $this::DB_TABLE_PK);
```

will translate to

```
UPDATE $this::DB_TABLE SET $this WHERE $this::DB_TABLE_PK
```

and in your example  above $this::DB_TABLE_PK is the name of the key ('project_id'), and not its value.

I would stick with

```
$this->db->where($this::DB_TABLE_PK, $pk)->update($this::DB_TABLE, $this);
```

Where $pk is the actual value of your PRIMARY KEY

Comment: This is exactly what i mean.
But what should i write instead of $pk in OOP programing ?